# How do I selectively upgrade Ubuntu to a specific point-release version?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

If I install 16.04.1 from ISO, how do I upgrade to 16.04.4, but prevent 16.04.5 from being installed?

Comment: If you install from ISO why not download and install 16.04.4 from ISO?  16.04 upgrade will always go to the highest point release. You can use `sudo apt-mark hold base-files` to hold point releases but that also prevents upgrading to .4

Comment: I assume that you already have 16.04.1 installed. As of now 16.04.4 is released and 16.04.5 is scheduled for August 2. If you upgrade 16.04.1 using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before August 2nd, it will upgrade your system to 16.04.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot that version manually after downloading the necessary files from website. The update feature only supports getting to the latest version (which is also accepted as the best)